# Center object when reshaping windows in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I am writing a simple obj model viewer. How do I make the object center of the screen when resizing windows? Currently it is moving to the right when I expand the screen, and move to the left when make the screen smaller.

There's a model transformation that center object at (0,0,0) (cx, cy, cz is the center of the object)

```
glm::mat4 proj = glm::perspective(glm::radians(40.0f), float(width)/float(height), ZNEAR, ZFAR);
glm::mat4 view = glm::lookAt(vec3(0,0.1,10),
                        vec3(0,0,0),
                        vec3(0,1,0));
glm::mat4 model = glm::scale(glm::mat4(1), vec3(zoom, zoom, zoom)) *
                  glm::translate(glm::mat4(1), vec3(-cx, -cy, -cz));

glm::mat4 mvp = proj * view * model;
```

and in vertex shader:

```
 gl_Position = mvp * vec4(VertexPosition, 1.0);
```

Reshape callback:

```
void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    height = h;
    width = w;
    // set viewport to stretch the CVV to fit exactly in the display window
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);

    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

Comment: You probably want to remake your projection matrix in your reshape function, because when looking at `glm::mat4 proj = glm::perspective(glm::radians(40.0f), float(width)/float(height), ZNEAR, ZFAR);
` you see it takes the width and height of the screen, which have changed. This will fix A problem, but i'm not sure its everything.

Comment: yes width and height are global variables so they are updated

Comment: Ok, so you call that line I mentioned every render cycle? Then I'm not really sure what the problem is. Do you have any additional code for your display? Do you use FBO's?

Comment: Yes that might be the problem. I'm using deferred shading that renders into a quad 0,0,1,1.

Comment: Yeah you should probably adjust the FBO sizes, else the viewport will be bigger/smaller than the FBO, which may have exactly the result you describe.